# How can I type an exclamation mark (!) in an HTML form in the w3m browser?

Tags: command-line, browser, w3m

I'm trying to type "!maven guava" in DuckDuckgo.com's search box in the `w3m` browser, but when I press `!`, `w3m` interprets it as a hotkey to run a shell command.

How can I escape this and just type a literal `!`?

This happens with both raw `w3m` in bash, and with the Emacs w3m plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the cursor above the text field **you first need to hit return** before you can insert text! Then, an exclamation mark shouldn't be an issue. :)